How to derive the volatility of options PL (hedged) as a function of implied volatility and measured realized volatility
This is my first time asking a questions. Apologies in advance if I mess something up. If this happens, please let me know if I do and I'll try to fix it.
My question is regarding the equation Euan Sinclair gave in his Option Trading: Pricing and Volatility Strategies Chapter 11 equation (11.22). The premise is, simulate $N$ geometric Brownian motions with volatility $\sigma$ as the price of the underlying. Calculate the P/L of selling 1 ATM option on that underlying priced at the real volatility $\sigma$. Sinclair argued that due to us observing the process at discrete intervals, although $\sigma$ represents the volatility of the true process, our measured realized volatility is given by $\sigma_{measured} \approx \sigma \pm \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{2N}} $ and the volatility of the P/L is given by $\sigma_{PL} \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}Vega\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$.
My question is, how is the last equation $\sigma_{PL} \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4}}Vega\frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{N}}$ derived?
Thank you in advance.

I think you need to provide more details from the book. Nobody is going into the textbook to check the derivation.
